# How to get label's height when text goes multiple lines

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am creating a label programatically in a detail view  on table cell click.aI am setting the text accordingly  and set the label height for that. This is my code :

```
NSString *mytitleString = [discussionData valueForKey:@"Name"];
 CGSize size =  [mytitleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(500, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
 float lbltitleheight = size.height;
 lbltitle.text = mytitleString;
```

but the problem is i am not able to set the height of lable if it is multiple line. How do i achieve this?

Comment: ok,you add two statement ...... label_mission.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        label_mission.numberOfLines = 0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you can't set labels size?
Did you try to set label as multiline:

```
NSString *mytitleString = [discussionData valueForKey:@"Name"];
CGSize size =  [mytitleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]  
                         constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(500, CGFLOAT_MAX) 
                             lineBreakMode:lbltitle.lineBreakMode];
lbltitle.frame = (CGRect){.oririn = lbltitle.frame.origin, .size = size};
lbltitle.numberOfLines = 0;
lbltitle.text = mytitleString;
```

I also recommend not use method `sizeToFit`, as when you will call this multiple times - label may become too narrow.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use

```
label.numberOfLines = 0; // allows label to have as many lines as needed
label.text = @"some long text";
[label sizeToFit];
NSLog(@"Label's frame is: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(label.frame));
```

Where the size will be adjusted accordingly.

Or you simply have to increase the height of your `UILabel` **Dynamically**. The `sizeWithFont constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` is the method to use.

```
//Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of your label
// FLT_MAX here simply means no constraint in height
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296, FLT_MAX);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];   

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Answer (score 2):

please try this:

```
CGFloat height=[mytitleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(500, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but you need to set numberOfLines is 0. Because it is 1 bydefault.

```
lbltitle.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 lbltitle.text = mytitleString;
 lbltitle.numberOfLines=0;
    [lbltitle sizeToFit];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 34.0)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setNumberOfLines:0];
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
label.minimumFontSize = 10.0;
[label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"YourFont" size:15]];
[label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
[label setText:yourText];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect rect_mission = CGRectMake(0, stringSize.height + stringSize_award.height+ 190, 280, stringSize_mission.height+60);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work correctly.
Try changing the `numberOfLines` for the label and set it to a max number which it can be extended.

Answer (score 1):

```
    CGFloat height=[yourlable sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:31] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(yourlable.frame.size.width,1000) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height;
```

and you get the dynamic height of label.